# Adicionar atributos na criação de arquivos

Tags: java, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos, java-8

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java que cria arquivos no diretório do usuário.

Então ao criar os arquivos eu precisava adicionar alguns atributos nas propriedades deles, para que eu posso identificar de onde originalizou este arquivo caso o usuário do sistema operacional copie esses arquivos e compartilhe com outras pessoas.

Existe alguma forma em Java de se fazer isso? Ex. em arquivos com formato MP3 existe atributos Autor, Descrição .

Comment: Se você está falando do que eu estou pensando, esse tipo de metadados é específico para cada tipo de arquivo. Por exemplo, MP3s geralmente usam o formato [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) (várias bibliotecas implementam suporte a ID3 em Java, veja [esse link](http://id3.org/Implementations)).

Comment: A maioria dos arquivos que vou criar é .bin, então não existe uma forma deu mudar algum atributo dele ou criar um novo para que eu posso colocar alguma informação que me ajude a identificar de quem era o arquivo? Na realizade eu estou trabalhando com Java web e estou fazendo uma central de download e precisava identificar no arquivo quem que fez o download. Eu andei olhando a API do Java e tem um tal de setOwner(), porem so da pra setar algum usuario que existe no sistema operacional da pessoa e não alguma String qualquer.

Comment: Setar o `owner` é apenas setar um atributo no sistema de arquivos (que pode ser modificado, no linux por exemplo basta usar o comando `chmod`). Se você está falando de arquivos binários de música "crua", metadados geralmente são demarcados em um arquivo textual [Cue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_(computing)).

Comment: Não é arquivos de musica. São firmwares que serão disponibilizados para download, porem gostaríamos de realizar um controle desses arquivos baixados pelo usuário. Estava olhando se dava para assinar os arquivos antes do download, porem so encontro para arquivos .zip e pdf.

Answer (score 1):

De um modo geral, quais atributos (metadados) um arquivo pode receber depende de duas coisas:

- Do sistema operacional, caso esses atributos sejam **externos** ao arquivo (i.e. não fazem parte do seu conteúdo);
- Do formato do arquivo, caso esses atributos sejam **internos** (ex.: os metadados que o MP3 suporta).

No seu caso, me parece que há o requisito de que estes sejam externos, uma vez que o formato não dá suporte a eles. Nesse caso, temos alguns problemas:

- A maioria dos SOs só suporta metadados simples (nome, data de criação, etc);
- Ainda que um SO suporte algo mais elaborado, esses metadados podem se perder caso o arquivo seja transferido de um computador para outro;
- O usuário sempre sempre pode alterar os dados à sua revelia.

Esse último ponto é importante, porque pelo seu último comentário me pareceu que você estava querendo fazer uma espécie de DRM. Isso é altamente inviável, sem garantia nenhuma, e pode trazer problemas - em particular quando aplicado a um formato de arquivo que não dá suporte nativo a isso. Se você quer "impedir que o usuário X copie o arquivo pro usuário Y", então receio que não há uma boa maneira de se fazer isso (e pessoalmente não considero um bom objetivo, mas é só minha opinião).

Se a questão não for essa, então por favor edite sua pergunta com mais detalhes, pois talvez exista alguma solução "fora da caixa" pro seu problema. Por exemplo, por que não colocar esse arquivo dentro de um `zip` e assinar o `zip`? Ao mesmo tempo, você pode mudar a extensão do `zip` (pra não deixar óbvio que é um `zip`) e modificar seu programa para usar o `zip` como entrada - e não o `bin` contido nele. Isso deve prevenir contra qualquer alteração acidental nos metadados (mas não as maliciosas, como já descrito acima).